# Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from './book';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { of } from 'rxjs';




@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {

  constructor() { }


  BOOKS : Book[]=[
    
    {"id": 1, "name" : "JavaScript",  "price" :"100", "description": "javscript"},
    {"id": 2, "name" : "Angualr",  "price" :"200", "description": "Angualr"},
    {"id": 3, "name" : "Sql server",  "price" :"3000", "description": "Sql server"},
    {"id": 4, "name" : "Typescript",  "price" :"5000", "description": "Typescript"},
    
  ]


  getBooks(): Observable<Book[]>{
    return Observable.of(this.BOOKS);
  }
}
```

Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)

i tried both import statement still it giving the

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)
Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.ts(2339)

Comment: `return Observable.of(this.BOOKS)` should be `return of(this.BOOKS)`

Comment: https://rxjs.dev/guide/v6/migration